# Parametric Equation of a Circle in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, math

```
Private Sub AutoSet(angle As Integer, radius As Double)
    Dim degrees As Integer = angle * (Math.PI / 180)
    'Radius is also the strength of the shot * 4, due to the aiming circle being ~400 pixels
    Dim setX As Double = (radius * 4) * (Math.Cos(angle))
    Dim setY As Double = (radius * 4) * (Math.Cos(angle))
    'Dim setY As Double = (radius * 4) * (Math.Sin(angle))

    'Center Tank
    Dim tankX As Double = tankIcon.Location.X '- 10
    Dim tankY As Double = tankIcon.Location.Y '- 5

    Dim ClickX As Integer = tankX + setX
    Dim ClickY As Integer = tankY - setY

    Graphics.FromImage(mainImageFrame.Image).FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, ClickX, ClickY, 10, 10)
    mainImageFrame.Refresh()
    MetroLabel3.Text = setX
    MetroLabel4.Text = setY 

End Sub

Private Sub MetroButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MetroButton1.Click
    AutoSet(angleTrackbar.Value, powerTrackbar.Value)
End Sub
```

---

Since I'm not allowed to actually post the screen shot, here is the link to the screenshot of the actual code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLNkf.png

Assume:

```
powerTrackbar.Value = 56
angleTrackbar.Value = 75
```

The problem with what I am attempting to do is get the X and Y values as seen from the applet on this page: http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html. 
Using the code above and comparing the MetroLabel3/4 output to WolframAlpha with the same formula but with manually switching the variables for the number: `(56*4) * (cos(75))`

I have tried numerous versions of RadianToDegree and vice versa functions within my code to no avail.
The only thing I am able to get to match up with WolframAlpha is when I use its "Radian" function compared to the normal Degree. I am unable to post more screenshots since I do not have a high enough reputation so I guess you'll have to take my word for the use of its functions. Although to manually turn on, simply append `&a=TrigRD_R` for radians or `&a=TrigRD_D` to the end of the WolframAlpha URL on the result page.

The expected result (I assume) of my function is ~`57.97` as per Degree mode on WolframAlpha. The actual output with this current code is ~`206.47..`

I cannot figure out the reason for VB.Net to not being able to output the correct number while WolframAlpha is capable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this formula to translate function argument in degrees to radians needed for Sin/Cos

```
Dim RadiansAngle As Double = DegreesAngle * (Math.PI / 180)
56 * 4 * Cos(75) = 224 * Cos(1.3 radians) = 224 * 0.26 ~ 58
```